# Highlighted text in Visual Studio appeared suddenly

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suddenly one word got highlighted in VS code and every time I type it anywhere it gets[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q8jq.jpg) highlighted. Pretty annoying, but at the same time can be useful. Any idea how to remove / add this highlights?

Comment: Check the Find widget - Ctrl+F or the Search panel - Ctrl+Shift+F.  Probably this word there - clear it to get rid of the highlighting.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I didn't realize it was open as I was concentrating so much. But you are absolutely right. Exactly that was the problem. It's like looking for something which is in front of your exes and still not seeing it :) Thanks again!